# How to group numeric data into ranges in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails 3.2 app I have the following model

```
create_table "people", do |t|
  t.integer  "height"
end
```

The `height` attribute is a person's height in cm.

I now want to group the data in this table by 5cm height classes, and return a count for each height class. e.g.,

```
{"height_classes":[150-155, 155-160, 160-165],"height_counts":[1, 3, 11]}
```

How can I group by classes like this?

So far I've used the following:

```
step = 5
data = People.all.sort_by &:length
height_classes = data.map{ |d| d.height - (d.length % step) }.uniq
height_counts = height_classes.map{ |hc| data.select{ |d| d.length - (d.length % step) == l }.count}
```

But this is not fully meeting my needs. What I would to achieve is:

- The height_classes run from the minimum to maximum values in the
  height column (but adjusted to a 5cm class - i.e. if the minimum
  value is 172 the grouping should be 170-175)
- Any empty classes should be included, with a count of zero
- The `height_classes` should be a string displaying the range of
  values

Is this possible?

Comment: this `[150..155, 155..160]` works in console as array of ranges, but perhaps you need nonintersecting ranges like this: `[150...155, 155...160]`. But maybe another Model is better for this spec.

Comment: thanks zishe. How would I use this to group my People model by height ranges? Forgive my confusion

Comment: It's really don't worth it. Just create Model AgeRange, it's better to separate this concept.